# Plotting bar graphs using a for-loop and ggplot2 package in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am working in R, using the ggplot package. I am trying to create bar graphs which show the density of trees of different sizes classes for each of my 200 plots. I've successfully made graphs for single plots by taking the ggplot code out of the `for`-loop and changing `i` to the plot number of interest (e.g. for plot 5, `data=data[data$Plot==5,]`). But whenever I try to automate the process using a `for` loop, I get blank graphs (x and y axis labelled, but no bars/data plotted). If anyone has any suggestions, I would be very grateful!

Summary of my data:

data (2000 obs of 3 variables)

- Plot: int (200 plots, repeated for each size class)
- SizeClass: int (10 size classes, repeated for each plot)
- Density_1998: int (number of trees per hectare in each size class for each plot)

Code:

```
plot.list <- unique(data$Plot)

for(i in 1:length(plot.list)) {
  print(ggplot(data = data[data$Plot == i, ], 
               aes(x = SizeClass, y = Density_1998)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_x_continuous(name = "Size Class(cm)")+ 
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Density (per ha)")
}
```

Comment: Rather than for loops, these days I tend to apply ggplot over grouped data using the dplyr::group_by and tidyr::nest functions to group and nest the data,  followed by purrr::map or purrr::map2 to apply a ggplot function over the nested data. A good example can be found here: http://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2017-03-29-make-ggplot2-purrr/

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data (e.g. `dput(data[data$Plot %in% c(1, 2)])`) that reproduces this error?